# Vector problem and steepest direction

Tags: linear-algebra

For any plane $P$ which is not parallel to the $x-y$ plane, define the steepest direction
on $P$ to be the direction of any vector which lies in $P$ and which makes the largest
(acute) angle with the $x-y$ plane.
a) Let $P$ be the plane through the origin with normal vector $n$. Derive a formula, in
terms of $n$, for a vector $w$ which points in the steepest direction on $P$
b) Now let $P$ be the plane through the origin which contains two non-parallel vectors
$u$ and $v$, where $u$ and $v$ do not both lie in the $x-y$ plane. Derive a formula, in terms
of $u$ and $v$, for a vector $w$ which points in the steepest direction on $P$.

My attempt and insight: Does direction of vector mean actually to find such angle? How can I visualize it or draw on paper?
For a) only thing I know is that scalar product of $n$ and $w$ is 0. Don't know how to proceed further. And b) seems even more trickier to solve.

Comment: Hint: consider the line of intersection between $P$ and the $x,y$ plane. Look for vectors that are orthogonal to each other, like $n$ and $w.$ Think about formulas that produce vectors orthogonal to other vectors.

Comment: It might help also to consider that the angle a vector makes with the $xy$-plane is $\frac \pi 2$ minus the angle that the vector makes with the $z$-axis.