# How to draw vector: steepest direction on Plane

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, vectors

The problem is, someone asked before [Vector problem and steepest direction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3256397/vector-problem-and-steepest-direction):

> For any plane P which is not parallel to the x-y plane, define the steepest direction
> on P to be the direction of any vector which lies in P and which makes the largest
> (acute) angle with the x-y plane.

> a) Let P be the plane through the origin with normal vector n. Derive a formula, in
> terms of n, for a vector w which points in the steepest direction on P

And the answer [image]

my drawing here[image]

If $\vec{w}$ is what I draw in the paper, that would be $w=k\times n$, I don't know why the answer gives one more cross-product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\vec{k} \times \vec{n}$ is a vector that sits in both the $x$-$y$ plane and $\mathscr{P}$, because it is normal to the normal of both planes. This means that its angle to the $x$-$y$ is always $0$, so this doesn't work.

In your drawing, it's not clear how $\vec{w}$ is defined, as it depends on how you crop the plane into the picture. Drawing both planes, their intersections and the vectors $\vec{k}$ and $\vec{n}$ coming out of the origin probably helps to visualise.

Intuitively you want a vector that's in $\mathscr{P}$ and points as 'far away' from the $x$-$y$ plane as possible, and this is achieved by being normal to the line where the $x$-$y$ plane and $\mathscr{P}$ intersect.  The vector $\vec{k} \times \vec{n}$ runs along that line. So $\vec{w}$ needs to be in $\mathscr{P}$ (i.e. it is normal to $\vec{n}$) and normal to $\vec{k} \times \vec{n}$, and so $\vec{w}=\vec{n} \times (\vec{k} \times \vec{n})$ does the job.

Comment: but ⃗ ×(⃗ ×⃗ ) would be 90degree they want slightly smaller than 90

Comment: $\vec{n} \times ( \vec{k} \times \vec{n})$ does not generally point 90 degrees away from the $x$-$y$ plane (it only does that when $\mathscr{P}$ is parallel to the $z$ axis), it points 90 degrees away from the line where $\mathscr{P}$ and the $x$-$y$ plane meet, while still being in $\mathscr{P}$. I still recommend you draw a diagram, keep in mind that $ \vec{x} \times \vec{y}$ is always perpendicular to $ \vec{x} $ and $ \vec{y}$

Comment: Got that finally! Thanks!!